# What kind of rivet is this on an Andersen storm door?

Tags: doors, windows, screens, rivets

I need to move a hinge on an Andersen storm door and noticed that they had rivets - what kind of rivet is this?  They say the size is 3/16 X 9/32.  Is it a pop rivet or a blind rivet?  I don't know anything about rivets.

[image]

Here's a video https://youtu.be/rJP34RkoHe0?t=108

I'd like to just buy some rivets to move it rather than buying an entire hinge assembly.  If they are hard to get - is there a simpler replacement I can use?

Comment: Is there enough metal in the frame to tap a 10-32 hole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call them "[drive rivets](https://www.google.com/search?q=drive%20rivets&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850&sxsrf=ALeKk024A9cr3I4CSios9sOyDoAmmYUePw:1592600950550&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6p7Tv5I7qAhWDWM0KHZzMDFMQ_AUoAnoECA4QBA&biw=1618&bih=947)", as you simply slip them into the hole and drive the pin in. They're readily available at well-stocked hardware stores. Andersen uses 1/8" and 3/16" sizes, if I recall correctly.

For your application you could also simply use corrosion-resistant sheet metal screws, or, as Jimmy Fix-it suggests, pop rivets.